# Binding to CroppedBitmap SourceRect

Tags: c#, wpf, image, crop

I have a Rect dependency property CropMediumRect which hold the cropping coördinates for the image.

When I bind this to the SourceRect prop of the CroppedBitmap nothing happens. It shows the full image.
However when I put the values of CropMediumRect directly in the SourceRect it does work.

Why doesn't it work with the binding?

Not working code:

```
<Image MaxHeight="55"
         MaxWidth="55"
         Stretch="Uniform"
         Margin="5">
<Image.Source>
    <CroppedBitmap Source="{Binding Photo.MediumUrl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 SourceRect="{Binding CropMediumRect}"   >
    </CroppedBitmap>
</Image.Source>
```

Working code:

```
<Image MaxHeight="55"
         MaxWidth="55"
         Stretch="Uniform"
         Margin="5">
<Image.Source>
    <CroppedBitmap Source="{Binding Photo.MediumUrl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            SourceRect="131 0 500 500"   >
    </CroppedBitmap>
</Image.Source>
```

I do see an error in the output window saying: Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='131,0,500,500' but I don't see what's wrong with it.
It's the same when I enter the values manually.

Comment: and your `CropMediumRect` is `System.Windows.Int32Rect`?

Comment: @dkozl nope, it was a Rect. I've changed it to Int32Rect and now it works fine. How stupid :) If you answer this post I mark your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CroppedBitmap.SourceRect` expects a value of `System.Windows.Int32Rect` type and binding to a property of `System.Windows.Rect` type will not work.